# Read an undefined number of lines from standard input

Tags: c#

I have an unknown number of lines of input. I know that each line is an integer, and I need to make an array with all the lines, for example:

Input:

```
12
1
3
4
5
```

and I need to get it as an array: `{12,1,3,4,5}`

I have the below code, but I can't get all the lines, and I can't debug the code because I need to send it to test it.

```
List<int> input = new List<int>();

string line;
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
     input.Add(int.Parse(Console.In.ReadLine()));
}

StockItem[] stock = new StockItem[input.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < stock.Length; i++) {
    stock[i] = new StockItem(input.ElementAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Give Linqpad a try, you can compile and pseudo-debug easily without VS. http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't see it, my spell checker is setted to Spanish and all my text is with the red marker, sorry about that.

Comment: [Ideone](http://ideone.com) is also good if you need to provide input.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
List<int> input = new List<int>();

// As long as there are nonempty items read the input
// then add the item to the list    
string line;
while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null && line != "") {
     input.Add(int.Parse(line));
}

// To access the list elements simply use the operator [], instead of ElementAt:
StockItem[] stock = new StockItem[input.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < stock.Length; i++) {
    stock[i] = new StockItem(input[i]);
}
```

Comment: `while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = Console.ReadLine()))` would look nicer :)

Comment: @minitech, Yes, at first I thought write it in the way you wrote, But after that I thought may be is a little confusing.

Comment: The problem isn't the sintaxis, i'm not starting with C# but i don't know why this solutions doesn't work (no, your solution didn't work either) :( i'm going to continue looking for it, thank you!!

Comment: @SaeedAmiri ok, i trust you, and i compile it in my head and it should works, the problem must be mine... thank you for your solution, i`m using it :)

Comment: @Santanor, [See IDEOne sample](http://ideone.com/OInfe). difference in using `&& line != ""` actually when your input is `String.Empty` without this checking you will get an exception.

Comment: @Santanor An important thing to notice is the `()` around `line = Console.ReadLine()`, as these force this part to evaluate first; otherwise, you will get an Exception similar "cannot convert string to bool".

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually need the ids in an array? I would probably try something like this:

```
    // Use a function that takes a StringReader as an input.
    // That way you can supply test data without using the Console class.
    static StockItem[] ReadItems(StringReader input)
    {
      var stock = new List<StockItem>();

      // Only call ReadLine once per iteration of the loop.
      // I expect this is why you're not getting all the data.
      string line = input.ReadLine();
      while( ! string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) ) {

        int id;
        // Use int.TryParse so you can deal with bad data.
        if( int.TryParse(line, out id) ) { 
          stock.Add(new Stock(id));
        }

        line = input.ReadLine();
      }

      // No need to build an populate an array yourself. 
      // There's a linq function for that.
      return stock.ToArray();
    }
```

Then you can call it with

```
  var stock = ReadItems(Console.In);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list is a good approach. But you should think about limiting the total number of rows.

Besides, the OP did not say, that empty lines should terminate the list!

So one should check for null only.

See [How to detect EOF on the console in C#? What does Console.ReadLine() returns upon EOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526669/how-to-detect-eof-on-the-console-in-c-what-does-console-readline-returns-upo)