# How to detect EOF on the console in C#? What does Console.ReadLine() returns upon EOF?

Tags: c#, input, stream, console, eof

I would like to read lines from console until EOF. I came up with this solution but I don't know if it is correct one.

```
        String line;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
        }
```

Comment: Type Ctrl+Z and see what happens.

Answer (score 7):

[Console.ReadLine Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) returns :

> The next line of characters from the input stream, or null if no more
>   lines are available.

Question : I came up with this solution but I don't know if it is correct one!

Answer : Yes, your code is correct.

Also, please go through the added link in the answer to know more about its uses.